# How can I achieve multi-threading in Python? [socket programming]

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, sockets

I am trying to create *a separate thread in a client* that revives messages from a *server socket in a non-blocking manner*. Since my original code is too long and a bit of a hassle to explain in order to understand it, I have created an example program which focuses on what I want to do. I try to create two separate threads , say `Thread t1` and `Thread t2`. `Thread t1` polls the socket to check for any received data whereas `Thread t2` does whatever task it is assigned to do. What I am expecting it to do is, `Thread t1` always polls and if a data is received it prints it on the screen and `Thread t2` executes in parallel doing whatever it is doing. But, I cannot get it working for some reason.

My example program is:

```
import threading
import time
import threading
from time import sleep
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 5555))
s.setblocking(0)
s.sendall(str.encode('Initial Hello'))

def this_thing():
    while True:
        try:
           data = s.recv(4096)
            print(data.decode('utf-8'))
        except:
            pass / break #not sure which one to use. Neither of it works

def that_thing():
    for i in range(10000):
        sleep(3)
        s.sendall(str.encode('Hello')
        print('happening2')

threading.Thread(target=this_thing(), args=[]).start()
threading.Thread(target=that_thing(), args=[]).start()
```

***Note:*** The server socket is a simple server that sends a message to all connected sockets if a message was received by it.
When I run the program by **breaking out in the exception** in `Thread t1`, only my `Thread t2` is keeps running.  *I.e `Thread t1` does not receive any data sent from the server*

Comment: you shouldn't ever pass in an except block, catch the exception and log it or just print it. To catch any exception you can just do, try: code() except Exception as e: print(e). The more specific the exception the better though.

Comment: @chatton : The exception is: `[WinError 10035] A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately`
Which makes sense, but if i change the socket to blocking it never really gets out of `Thread t1` until I receive a message which is not what I want to do. Any way around this?

Comment: threading.Thread(target=this_thing(), args=[]).start(), I'm pretty sure the target is supposed to be the function itself, and not the result of the function call.

target=this_thing() -> target=this_thing

I think what's happening now is that during creation of the first thread it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: from the docs "target is the callable object to be invoked by the run() method" https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html 

in this case, this_thing and that_thing are the callable objects.

Comment: @chatton , yes. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: you should be able to simply change target=this_thing() to target=this_thing and the same for that_thing

Comment: Thanks a ton @chatton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the "target" argument takes a callable object.

from the docs docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

"target is the callable object to be invoked by the run() method"

in your version

```
threading.Thread(target=this_thing(), args=[]).start()
threading.Thread(target=that_thing(), args=[]).start()
```

when you say target=this_thing(), it will try and evaluate the value of a call to this_thing, in your case, it will enter a while True loop, and then if it was to finish it would evaluate to None.

What you want to do is replace these 2 lines with

```
threading.Thread(target=this_thing, args=[]).start()
threading.Thread(target=that_thing, args=[]).start()
```

Note that you are now passing in the function itself. A function is a callable object.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution for python 3+ isn't multithreading but asyncio.

Check out this awesome speech from David Beazley on the matter (49 mins):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzfHjytDceU

Asyncio / sockets example: https://gist.github.com/gregvish/7665915